# GmailAdd on universalActions Text Internationalization

Tags: internationalization, multilingual, gmail-addons

I have been developing a GmailAddon. It has a `universalAction` and it implemented in appscript.json from https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions. My universalaction block is

```
"universalActions": [{
"text": "Settings",
"runFunction": "createSettingsResponse"
}]
```

Problem is my Addon should be supports multi language. How I change the text of universalActions with current language?

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem with `Card Actions` and remove `universalActions` block. Creatting any action per Cards you can reach more details from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action.